# Movie where a family of four play a board game that punishes players when they lie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie on TV.

I don't recall how it started, but there is this board game where a big head asks a "yes"/"no" question and the player will answer by lying or telling the truth. The game was played by a family (dad, mom, son and daughter) and it will allow only one lie. If the player lies again, then he/she is punished with a trial. I just remember one of the trials, like the whole family had to escape from a deep pit (like the one where Batman was thrown by Bane in *The Dark Knight Rises*).

I barely remember a couple of questions that the family members were asked:

- Q for dad: Have you ever cheated on your wife? A: No.
- Q for the son: Have you been sneaking when your sister is changing? A: No.

It seems like it's a movie only for TV and never released in theaters. It has low quality FX. I tried searching for movies that were similar to, based on, or copies of *Jumanji*.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This could be the German movie ***[Manatu – Nur die Wahrheit rettet Dich](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manatu_%E2%80%93_Nur_die_Wahrheit_rettet_Dich)*** (2007). It was produced for the German TV channel, Sat. 1.

In the movie, a family of four receives a board game and once start playing, they can't leave the house anymore. When a player lands on a red field, a ghost will ask the player three questions that need to be answered truthfully, otherwise the whole family gets teleported to a deep well. In the well, they stand on small platforms and have to work together to escape.

Comment: Yes, that is the movie I was looking for. Thank you buddy!